# Is there a way to detect the end of binary file using readUTF() in Java?

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I would like to know is it possible to detect the end of the binary file while using readUTF()/readInt()/etc. functions (DataInputStream methods). Here's the code

```
    try(DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.dat")))){
        String input;
        while((input = br.readUTF()) != null){ //something like that
            //some code
        }
    }catch(IOException error){
        //handling exception
    }
```

If not what's recommended solution for such cases? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do the Javadocs for [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) say?

Comment: you can do `while(reader.available() > 0)`

Comment: `InputStream.available()` only tell how many bytes can be read without blocking, so it is not a correct solution. If you really want to make `available()` work, it is possible to read the entire file into a byte buffer first and then read from the buffer using a  `ByteArrayInputStream`. I would just change your current code to catch an `EOFException` instead.

Comment: It throws `EOFException` at end of stream. Catch it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on ***[readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF--)*** from the docs, I don't see an elegant way to do it, maybe you could read until it hits `EOFException` like this:

```
    while(true){
        try{
            input = reader.readUTF();
        }
        catch(EOFException e) {
            //....
        }
    }
```